# conditional/processing on the dummy data column to create new dummy column

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Following is my query.

```
Select [A],[C]
      ,CASE WHEN [A]>19999 and [A]<30000 THEN '12' ELSE '21' END AS 'dummy1'
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),1,4) as YEARDummy
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),5,2) as MONTHDummy
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),7,2) as DAYDummy
    ,CASE WHEN MONTHDummy>0 and DAYDummy<31 THEN '30dayas' ELSE 'xyz' END AS Dummy4
From TableYearlyData
```

I want to do conditional/processing on the dummy data column to create new dummy column. How can I use a dummy column to create a new dummy column?

Comment: I am creating a dummy column based on the value of C. I want to use the value which is now in dummy column to create new dummy column. I do not want to write above query by using the same 'Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),5,2) as MONTHDummy
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),7,2) as DAYDummy' in the Cash statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the help of [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
;WITH CTE AS (Select [A],[C]
      ,CASE WHEN [A]>19999 and [A]<30000 THEN '12' ELSE '21' END AS 'dummy1'
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),1,4) as YEARDummy
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),5,2) as MONTHDummy
    ,Substring(CAST(C AS varchar(9)),7,2) as DAYDummy
    --,CASE WHEN MONTHDummy>0 and DAYDummy<31 THEN '30dayas' ELSE 'xyz' END AS Dummy4
From TableYearlyData)

-- here you can apply your CASE with YEARDummy,MONTHDummy,DAYDummy column
SELECT *,CASE WHEN MONTHDummy>0 and DAYDummy<31 THEN '30dayas' ELSE 'xyz' END AS Dummy4 
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks. above query works fine. Can you tell where this CTE table stored as temporary data.?

Comment: @PratikRamani glad it help you.-- CTE is like a derived table: it’s not stored as an object and is valid only during the execution of the primary statement.CTE results are not stored anywhere, they don't produce results a CTE is just a definition.   
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Answer (score 1):

Besides the mentioned CTE, you could also use a subquery.

```
SELECT  [A]
  , [C]
  , CASE WHEN MONTHDummy > 0
              AND DAYDummy < 31 THEN '30dayas'
         ELSE 'xyz'
    END AS Dummy4
FROM    (SELECT [A]
          , [C]
          , CASE WHEN [A] > 19999
                      AND [A] < 30000 THEN '12'
                 ELSE '21'
            END AS 'dummy1'
          , SUBSTRING(CAST(C AS varchar(9)), 1, 4) AS YEARDummy
          , SUBSTRING(CAST(C AS varchar(9)), 5, 2) AS MONTHDummy
          , SUBSTRING(CAST(C AS varchar(9)), 7, 2) AS DAYDummy
     FROM   TableYearlyData
    ) AS SUB
```